# Por que as bibliotecas usam "! function_exists('funcao')" sempre quando há uma declaração de uma função?

Tags: php, funções

Já usei várias bibliotecas PHP e percebi que as mesmas sempre utilizam a mesma declaração, sempre que há uma declaração de uma nova função.

```
if (! function_exists('funcao')) {
    function funcao($arg) {

    }
}
```

Ou seja, a função só deve ser declarada caso não existir.

Mas por que desse tipo de prática? Por que se preocupar se a função existe ou não?

Se isso é para evitar colisão de nomes, com as novas versões do PHP, que implementam `namespace`, que funcionam também para funções, há necessidade de fazer tal declaração?

Comment: Talvez para suportar versões antigas do PHP que não tem a função, por exemplo, `hash_equals` que só tem no PHP 5.6 (e superior) e dar suporte para quem usa PHP 5.5 de alguma maneira. Isso pode ocorrer dentro do próprio "sistema", o Wordpress tem várias versões... Se fizer um plugin pode ser que exista ou não uma função, dependendo da versão que tiver sendo utilizada, dai utiliza o `function_exists` para saber se existe ou não. Esses são os possíveis usos que vejo. :P

Comment: Entendi, @Inkeliz, uma falta de padronização nesse caso, pode ferrar com tudo, já que em PHP colisão de funções gera um Fatal Error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um exemplo comum disto é Laravel, especificamente o motivo é que as funções tem nomes bem *simplórios* e de fácil conflito com outros scripts, pois pode ser que outros scripts já tenham o usado

O motivo de não usar namespaces para funções, o que é possível, é para que tais funções sejam acessíveis sem precisar chama-las com namespace ou `use function`, isto é para facilitar, pois são uma série de funções simples como disse.

> No caso do Laravel especifico se observar na verdade são uma série de funções uteis que em um futuro até o próprio PHP poderia implementar no núcleo, opinião minha

Se você tiver uma função que conflita com uma função existente, podendo ser nativa ou não, isto causará uma `Exception`, então isto seria um *efeito colateral*, conforme o [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#side-effects) este é um dos *efeitos colaterais* (side-effects) que devemos evitar, ou seja junto as declarações nunca deve-se fazer:

- Alterar comportamentos (ex: `ini_set`, `error_reporting`)
- Enviar resposta para o saída (output)
- Causar `Exception`

Ou seja as funções podem fazer isto, mas somente no momento que são chamadas.

### Exemplo de efeitos colaterais:

Imagine que tenhamos um `global.php` que deve conter as declarações, ele será incluído em todos arquivos:

```
<?php

//Pode causar um efeito colateral se já existir uma função com mesmo nome
function view()
{
   //Algo aqui....
}

//Pode causar efeito colateral acaso file.php não exista
include 'file.php';

//Causa efeito colateral, pois envia conteúdo para a saída
echo "<html>\n";
```

### Exemplo de declaração e uso sem efeito colateral:

global.php:

```
<?php

//Evita conflito com outros scripts
if (!function_exists('view')) {
    function view()
    {
        //Algo aqui....
    }
}
```

3rdparty.php:

Arquivo de "terceiros", o qual você está usando:

```
<?php

function foo() { ... }
function view() { ... }
function bar() { ... }
```

index.php:

```
<?php

include '3rdparty.php';
include 'global.php';
include 'file.php';

echo "<html>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente esse tipo de verificação serve mais para fazer um polyfill, ou seja, ter uma função que faça algo caso a mesma não exista.

Um uso comum que eu vejo para estes casos é quanto a suporte para multi byte.
Vamos olhar a função `str_len` para termos uma idéia melhor.

Temos três extensões que providenciam uma função de contagem de caracteres em uma string:

- [mb](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)
- [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php)
- [php nativo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)

Note que a função nativa do php não trata corretamente os caracteres que estejam em algumas codificações (como UTF-8), pois os caracteres podem ocupar mais de 1 byte.

Por este motivo, o mais correto é usar a função de contagem do mb ou do iconv. Mas qual delas está disponível?

Com o seguinte código, podemos declarar facilmente uma função de acordo com as extensões que estão disponíveis no php:

```
if(function_exists('iconv_strlen')) {
  function meu_strlen($entrada) {
    return iconv_strlen($entrada);
  }
} else if (function_exists('mb_strlen') {
  function meu_strlen($entrada) {
    return mb_strlen($entrada);
  }
} else {
  /* Tudo falhou, vamos usar a função do PHP mesmo :( */
  function meu_strlen($entrada) {
    return strlen($entrada);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Isso faz com que tal função só seja definida caso ela não exista ainda.
Interessante caso você precise sobrescrever alguma delas, você define a sua, e aí, o framework "pergunta":
Essa função aqui que eu vou definir agora, o usuário já a fez antes? Se sim, não redefinirei, vou deixá-lo usar a que ele fez. Senão, vou definí-la